# Copy the Same formula in excel to each cell in a comlumn but only change the formula?

Tags: excel, vba

I am using a formula in excel to add all the data with the same date in the column before with `=SUMIF(A2:A150,C1,B2:B150)`

Is there any way to copy the formula down the column but with the same range but different row: `=SUMIF(A2:A150,C(the row it is in),B2:B150)`

Instead, when i copy the formula down the column, it does: `=SUMIF(A3:A151,C2,B3:B151)` and adds one to every value.

**Is there any way to use a variable to only change the row,** 
Thanks.

Comment: You mean `=SUMIF($A$2:$A$150,C1,$B$2:$B$150)`? Also are you looking for a formula answer, or VBA?

Answer (score 0):

Make the sum range and criteria range *row absolute*.

```
range("d1:d149").formula = "=SUMIF(A$2:A$150, C1, B$2:B$150)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

=SUMIF($A$2:$A$150,$C1,$B$2:$B$150)

Putting $ sign locks the cell range. Alternatively, you can use F4 on your keyboard to lock cells, F4 puts the $ automatically with you the need for typing.